# Lua error relating to Scribunto Mediwiki Infobox

Tags: php, lua

I am trying to get my head around setting up a MediaWiki through hosting rather than local.

The current error I am getting is:

```
Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter exited with status .Expression error: Unexpected < operator.Lua error: Internal error: The interpreter exited with status .
```

Firstly there is no status number, secondly this is the new error after changing the config in LocalSettings from default path to within the Lua extention folder. The error I was getting was:

> Lua error: Cannot create process: proc_open(/**MY
> DOMAIN**/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_64_generic/):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directoryExpression error:
> Unexpected < operator.Lua error: Cannot create process:
> proc_open(/**MY
> DOMAIN**/extensions/Scribunto/includes/engines/LuaStandalone/binaries/lua5_1_5_linux_64_generic/):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I gather that Scribunto is not able to create an error log file? I have enabled Proc_close and Proc_open with my hosting.

This is is way above my skillset some I'm fumbling round in a PHP dark room.

Any thoughts would be great. I just want to create InfoBoxes!!!!!!

Thanks

Tim